# using npm to install expo-cli --global to react setting, error occurs

Tags: react-native

....

npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.3.3 requires a peer of react-refresh@^0.8.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

am i have to install another package peer to react-refresh ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this command :
`npm install -D @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin react-refresh`